# Fancybox trigger click not working online (after Ajax request)

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

My jQuery Fancybox works perfectly on my local computer, but it doesn't work well on my live website.

Locally, gallery starts with a single click only when it takes two clicks online.

Thanks for your help!

Here is my code:

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.photo', function(e){

        if (e.which == 1) {

            var clicked = $(this);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'gallery.php?title="' + encodeURIComponent($(this).attr("data-name")) + '"',
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function(data){

                if(data != ''){
                    $('<div class="new-gallery hidden"></div>').insertAfter(clicked);
                    for (var i = 0; i <= data.length ; i++) {
                        (function(i) {
                            $('<a class="fancybox" href="'+ data[i].dir +'" rel="gallery" title="'+ data[i].title +'"><img src="'+ data[i].dir +'" alt=""/></a>')
                            .appendTo('.new-gallery');
                        })(i);
                    }
                }

            });

            $(".fancybox")
                .fancybox({
                    helpers   : { 
                        overlay : {closeClick: false},
                    }
                });
        }

    });

    $(document).on('click', '.photo', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".fancybox").eq(0).trigger("click");
    });
```

Comment: Because fancybox won't be bound to the `.fancybox` selector until the first `mousedown` event bound to the `document` object. Take the fancybox initialization script out of the `mousedown` (`.on()` method) script and place it inside of a regular `.ready()` method

Comment: Still not working. I don't  understand how it's possible that there is a difference with jQuery between localhost and online server.